# Are hidden services portable?

Tags: onion-services, network-configuration

I understand hidden services and am planning to configure one on my laptop. I was just wondering, if I create a hidden service on my laptop at home will the hidden service still work with the same onion address on a different network such as at a coffee shop for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the .onion address stays the same no matter what network you're using to connect to the Tor network.

Answer (score 0):

Your onion address is calcaluted when you configure your Onion Service. Whenever you change networks Tor will realise this and update the service descriptor. So after some short amount of time your address will be reachable again indepent from the network which you're currently using.